# jQuery maskedinput triggers completed twice on paste

Tags: javascript, jquery, maskedinput

I'm facing this bug with jQuery maskedinput.

Pasting a value on an masked input triggers the completed event twice.
This behavior can be seen on their oficial website.

Open [this](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) link and click on `Demo`.
Select `Product Key` input and type `aa-999-a999`.
After that, try to paste the same value in the field.

There are some other issues related to NOT triggering the event on paste, but none of them helped me with this bug...

Dows anyone know why or had a similar problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just took a quick look, but it looks like `blurEvent` fires `checkVal`, and `#product` has the only `mask` call with a `completed` event that opens an `alert`. That's often a double-fire culprit. Try adding `completed:function(){alert("Now you typed: "+this.val());}` to another handler?

Comment: Hey @ruffin, thanks for your help.

You're right, blurEvent fires checkVal and this might be a problem.

What do you mean when you say 'add the completeted funcition to another handler'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I've tried a simplest case like this (using [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.0/dist/jquery.maskedinput.js) for `maskedinput.js`, though note that I edit it, below, and [this](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js) for `jquery-1.11.2.js`):

```
<html>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
          $.mask.definitions['~']='[+-]';
          $("#tin").mask("99-9999999",{completed:function(){alert("Now you typed: "+this.val());}});
       });
    </script>

    <table border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tax ID</td>
            <td><input type="text" tabindex="5" id="tin"></td>
            <td>99-9999999</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

And I edited the maskedinput source a bit to see when and from where stuff fires. [I'll paste.ee it here](http://paste.ee/p/TItih), but here are the main parts...

- Find the `.on("blur.mask")...` line
- Note that it's reusing the same function for `blur`, `keydown`, `input`, and `paste`.
- Add a `console.log` to tell you what specific event is firing each time to debug pasting.

Here's what I did (note that if you're using IE8-, you need to "protect" the `console.log` call or run it with Dev Tools open):

```
}).on("blur.mask", blurEvent).on("keydown.mask", keydownEvent).on("keypress.mask", keypressEvent).on("input.mask", function() {
    console.log("mask called: " + arguments[0].type); // <<< New debugging line.
    input.prop("readonly") || setTimeout(function() {
        var pos = checkVal(!0);
        input.caret(pos);
        tryFireCompleted("mask");
    }, 0);
}), chrome && android && input.off("input.mask").on("input.mask", androidInputEvent),
```

When you paste stuff in, two event handlers are called for the "same" action.

```
mask called: paste
mask called: input
```

Those both eventually call `tryFireCompleted`, which fires off the `.completed` function we set up in this line of our own code, above:

```
$("#tin").mask("99-9999999",{completed:function(){alert("Now you typed: "+this.val());}});
```

If you remove the `paste.mask` event handler, that problem will go away. Here's the crucial part:

`.on("input.mask paste.mask",`
... changes into...
`.on("input.mask",`
... so `paste.mask` is gone. (And before releasing to production, remove the `console.log` line, of course.)

Now that might work all by itself. Pastes were firing off `input`, so having `paste` too might be overkill. But I'd check around more before I used that as a permanent fix. I did try right-clicking a paste with the mouse, which was fine with this change. Not sure when `paste` is fired and `input` isn't.

If there *is* an edge case where `paste` is called and `input` isn't (or a case where you really would want `tryFireCompleted` to fire twice), you'll need to find a way to suppress the second `tryFireCompleted` with more convoluted code.

Without a `completed` function, though, firing off twice wouldn't be an obvious problem, I don't think, which explains why this might have slipped through. Good find.

Comment: Clearer impossible!

I was using the console.log stuff to debug, but in a different way.

I'll make the changes you've suggested and this should be enough for now.

I'll try to find something new in the weekend...

Thanks a ton, man!

Marked as accepted!

Cheers!

Comment: Good deal. Glad it helped!